# Missing "Run in terminal" in KDE

Tags: shell-script, scripting, kde

I switched to KDE from Gnome after seven years using the latter. I have everything configured already but I'm missing one option: the **run in terminal** prompt, when executing a script double clicking.

A script which does not need interaction is ok, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir abc
```

on double click, it creates the folder abc as expected.

However if the script runs a script that need a terminal, it won't work. For example I got the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/python/script/
python init.py
```

That python script need the user to input some numbers, however as the bash script wasn't run on a terminal, the python script won't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the solution.

I created a .desktop file which this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Path=/path/
Exec=python /path/init.py
Icon=/path/icon.png
Name=ProgramName
Terminal=true
```